# Function screen is touched or not

Tags: java, android, eclipse, screen

I can't find solution...
I want run firstfunc() if screen is not touched
I have firstfunc () I don't want run it if screen is touched

for it I need boolean function that returns true or false to determine screen is touched or not.
I tried to and `myView.setOnTouchListener(`  and

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return super.onTouchEvent(event);
           }
```

but it is not want I want...

Comment: What do you want exactly? The "onTouchEvent" only be invoked when the screen is TOUCHED, otherwise the screen is NOT TOUCHED!

Comment: I want run first func() if screen is not touched

Comment: Basically you can't, how do you know when the screen is NOT TOUCHED, the screen is only a tool to receive the signal TOUCH from user, if the user doesnt touch it, there are no signals at all, so the screen basically NOT TOUCHED all the time. I'm sorry but you can NOT do that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    //the whole screen becomes sensitive to touch
    mLinearLayoutMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
    mLinearLayoutMain.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    // put your code in here

    return false;//false indicates the event is not handled
}
```

}

in the layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main">
    <!-- your other views go here-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have 
func ()
{

}
I don't want run it if screen is touched

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement on `OnTouchListener` in which set a flag.
2. Set the event for #1 to the view which should sense the touch.

`class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener`

```
    View senceTouch;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      senceTouch = findViewById(R.id.view_id); 
      senceTouch.setOnTouchListener(this)

    }

      @Override 
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       // set flag here 
         return true; 
      }
 }
```

Comment: if I touch screen flag = true;
if I not touch screen how to set flag=false ?

Comment: Declare boolean flag at class level and by default its value will be false. False value of flag will indicate that screen is not touched.